# LuaLaTeX includegraphics

Tags: graphics, luatex

The following code shows adequatly both images when compiled with pdfLaTeX, but when compiled with LuaLaTeX, only the second image(PlanDeFerme5.pdf) is shown.

No error/warning is flagged in the log file.

The working version shows a reference to pdftex.map under the header: NON PDF SPECIAL IGNORED in the log file.

```
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored! <./Figures/YearRound5.pdf{E:/texmfs/data/pdftex/config
/pdftex.map}> <./Figures/SAU/PlanDeFerme5.pdf>] (calendreDebug.aux)
```

### Logs

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.0 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210)  (format=lualatex 2017.3.20)  30 JUN 2017 14:41
 restricted system commands enabled.
**calendreDebug.tex
(./calendreDebug.tex
LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 1
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2016/06/16 2.70003 OpenType layout system.
Lua module: lualibs 2016-04-06 2.4 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2016-04-06 2.4 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended co
llection.(using cache: E:/texmfs/data/luatex-cache/generic)
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is E:/texmfs/data/luatex-cache/generic/
names.
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader “fontloader-2016-06-16.lua” from kpse
-resolved path “E:/texmfs/install/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-2016-06-16.
lua”.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@state = 1
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 2
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 3
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version “3.023”
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 4
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is E:/texmfs/data/luatex-cache/generic/
names.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
.
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.365 seconds
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(E:/texmfs/install/tex/latex/a0poster/a0poster.cls
Document Class: a0poster 2004/01/31 v1.22b a0poster class (GK, MW)
(E:/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(E:/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from E:/texmfs/data/luatex-cache/ge
neric/names/luaotfload-names.luc(load luc: E:/texmfs/data/luatex-cache/generic/f
onts/otl/lmroman10-regular.luc))
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
\xkoord=\count87
\ykoord=\count88
\xscale=\count89
\yscale=\count90
\tausch=\dimen103
\Ausgabe=\write3

\openout3 = a0header.ps

(E:/texmfs/install/tex/latex/a0poster/a0size.sty
File: a0size.sty 2004/01/31 v1.22b a0poster class (GK, MW)
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `largesymbols' on input line 229.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 229.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 229.
\big@size=\dimen104
)(load luc: E:/texmfs/data/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman17-regular.luc)
)
(E:/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15


Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.

) (E:/texmfs/install/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(E:/texmfs/install/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
(E:/texmfs/install/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2016/10/09 v1.0u Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(E:/texmfs/install/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(E:/texmfs/install/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 99.

(E:/texmfs/install/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def
File: luatex.def 2017/01/12 v0.01h Graphics/Color for luaTeX

(E:/texmfs/install/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(E:/texmfs/install/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count91
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen105
\Gin@req@width=\dimen106
) (./calendreDebug.aux)
\openout1 = calendreDebug.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.

(E:/texmfs/install/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count92
\scratchdimen=\dimen107
\scratchbox=\box26
\nofMPsegments=\count93
\nofMParguments=\count94
\everyMPshowfont=\toks17
\MPscratchCnt=\count95
\MPscratchDim=\dimen108
\MPnumerator=\count96
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count97
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks18
) (E:/texmfs/install/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf

(E:/texmfs/install/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

(E:/texmfs/install/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
))
(E:/texmfs/install/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

(E:/texmfs/install/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

(E:/texmfs/install/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

(E:/texmfs/install/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX detected.
))))
(E:/texmfs/install/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)


(E:/texmfs/install/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.

(E:/texmfs/install/tex/generic/oberdiek/luatex-loader.sty
Package: luatex-loader 2016/05/16 v0.6 Lua module loader (HO)

(E:/texmfs/install/scripts/oberdiek/oberdiek.luatex.lua))
\pdftexcmds@toks=\toks19
)
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 43
8.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPEG
,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 456.
)
<./Figures/YearRound5.pdf, id=1, 2392.94pt x 3382.6375pt>
File: ./Figures/YearRound5.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)

<use ./Figures/YearRound5.pdf>
Package luatex.def Info: ./Figures/YearRound5.pdf used on input line 9.
(luatex.def)             Requested size: 910.01912pt x 1286.39632pt.

<./Figures/SAU/PlanDeFerme5.pdf, id=2, 614.295pt x 1011.78pt>
File: ./Figures/SAU/PlanDeFerme5.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)

<use ./Figures/SAU/PlanDeFerme5.pdf>
Package luatex.def Info: ./Figures/SAU/PlanDeFerme5.pdf used on input line 10.
(luatex.def)             Requested size: 910.01912pt x 1498.95482pt.
 [1


Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!<./Figures/YearRound5.pdf><./Figures/SAU/PlanDeFerme5.pd
f>] (./calendreDebug.aux)

 *File List*
a0poster.cls    2004/01/31 v1.22b a0poster class (GK, MW)
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
  a0size.sty    2004/01/31 v1.22b a0poster class (GK, MW)
inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2016/10/09 v1.0u Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  luatex.def    2017/01/12 v0.01h Graphics/Color for luaTeX
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
luatex-loader.sty    2016/05/16 v0.6 Lua module loader (HO)
./Figures/YearRound5.pdf
./Figures/SAU/PlanDeFerme5.pdf
 ***********

)

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 1700 strings out of 494568
 100000,89155 words of node,token memory allocated
 371 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 7 glue, 5 attribute, 40 glue_spec, 5 attribute_list
, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:55,3:15,4:1,5:11,6:1,7:26,8:11,9:28
 5666 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+200000
 16 fonts using 602543 bytes
 37i,5n,23p,264b,144s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
Output written on calendreDebug.pdf (1 page, 5388287 bytes).

PDF statistics: 42 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### TeX MWE

```
\listfiles 
\documentclass[portrait,a0,final]{a0poster}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{./Figures/YearRound5.pdf}} 
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{./Figures/SAU/PlanDeFerme5.pdf}} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) have you tried with other PDFs? Can we access these PDF files?

Comment: your mwe has `\listfiles` but you have not shown the list that this generates in the log

Comment: I have added the entire log.

Comment: I downloaded the two pdf image files and compiled your code under MacTeX2017, both LuaLaTeX 1.0.4 and pdfLaTeX. (Plus, `graphicx.sty 2017/06/01 v1.1a`, just in case it matters.) I experienced no problems, i.e, the LuaLaTeX-based output looks just the same as the pdfLaTeX-based output does.

Comment: Off-topic: You shouldn't be loading the `inputenc` package under Lua(La)TeX.

Comment: Can you update so you have lualatex 1.0.4 (the standard in the current texlive) instead of 1.0.0?

Comment: Thank you, updating LuaTex to 1.0.4 fixed the problem.  This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (MiKTeX 2.9.6360 NEXT)  (format=lualatex 2017.7.1)  1 JUL 2017 14:39

Comment: This was my first post, I am just wondering how to close it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by updating to LuaTeX 1.0.4

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as the OP's issue was solved by updating the LuaTeX to version 1.0.4.

Comment: Folks this isn't really off-topic. Why leave a message saying “This question does not fall within the scope of TeX, LaTeX or related typesetting systems”? I can understand answering the question or deleting the question, but declaring it off-topic is clearly wrong.